# Java Puzzler: busy wait threads stop working

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-synchronization, java-memory-model, busy-waiting

This is some sort of a Java Puzzler, that I stumbled across and can't really explain. Maybe somebody can?

The following program hangs after a short time. Sometimes after 2 outputs, sometimes after 80, but almost always before terminating correctly. You might have to run it a few times, if it doesn't happen the first time.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final WorkerThread[] threads = new WorkerThread[]{ new WorkerThread("Ping!"), new WorkerThread("Pong!") };
        threads[0].start();
        threads[1].start();

        Runnable work = new Runnable() {
            private int counter = 0;
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(counter + " : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                threads[counter++ % 2].setWork(this);
                if (counter == 100) {
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }
        };

        work.run();
    }
}

class WorkerThread extends Thread {
    private Runnable workToDo;

    public WorkerThread(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true){
            if (workToDo != null) {
                workToDo.run();
                workToDo = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public void setWork(Runnable newWork) {
        this.workToDo = newWork;
    }
}
```

Now, it's clear that busy waiting loops are not a great idea in general. But this not about improving, it's about understanding what is happening.

Since everything works as expected when `WorkerThread.setWork()` is `synchronized` or when the `WorkerThread.workToDo` field is set to `volatile` I suspect a memory issue.

But why exactly is it happening? Debugging doesn't help, once you start stepping through, everything behaves as expected.

An explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs right between these lines:

```
workToDo.run();
workToDo = null;
```

Suppose the following sequence of events occurs:

```
- Original Runnable runs.  "Ping!".setWork() called
- Ping! thread realizes workToDo != null, calls run(), the stops between those two lines
  - "Pong!".setWork() called
- Pong! thread realizes workToDo != null, calls run()
  - "Ping!".setWork() called
- Ping! thread resumes, sets workToDo = null, ignorantly discarding the new value
- Both threads now have workToDo = null, and the counter is frozen at 2,...,80
  Program hangs
```

Comment: I think there is also be a cache-coherency issue here too. Making `workToDo` a `volatile` or making `setWork` to `synchronized` will fix the cache-coherency by forcing the value of `workToDo` to be visible to all threads. However, it won't solve the race condition you have identified, that would require a lock or other construct to prevent another thread from calling `setWork()` while this thread is between `workToDo.run()` and `workToDo = null`.

Answer (score 2):

1. The first problem is that you are setting the `Runnable workToDo` from the `main` thread and then reading it in the 2 forked threads without synchronization.  Any time you modify a field in multiple threads, it should be marked as `volatile` or someone `synchronized`.

   ```
   private volatile Runnable workToDo;
   ```
2. Also, because multiple threads are doing `counter++` this also needs to be `synchronized`.  I recommend an `AtomicInteger` for that.

   ```
   private AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
   ...
   threads[counter.incrementAndGet() % 2].setWork(this);
   ```
3. But I think the *real* problem may be one of race conditions.  It is possible for both threads to set the `workToDo` to be the `Runnable` and then have them both return and set it back to be `null` so they will just spin forever.  I'm not sure how to fix that.

   ```
   1. threads[0] has it's `workToDo` set to the runnable.  It calls `run()`.
   2. at the same time threads[1] also calls `run()`.
   3. threads[0] sets the `workToDo` on itself and threads[1] to be the runnable.
   4. at the same time threads[1] does the same thing.
   5. threads[0] returns from the `run()` method and sets `workToDo` to be `null`.
   6. threads[1] returns from the `run()` method and sets `workToDo` to be `null`.
   7. They spin forever...
   ```

And, as you mention, the spin loop is crazy but I assume this is a demonstration thread program.

Comment: Use of a Object monitor (wait/notify) would also be advisable

Comment: Yeah @MadProgrammer.  I assume this is some sort of thread demo program or something.

Comment: The "should" part is clear, as explained above this fixes the problem. But why? Somehow the field contents seem to get lost and both threads are left with a view to a `null` field (hence busy-waiting forever). However, when you set a breakpoint at that time in a WorkerThread's `run()` method, the current thread halts and suddenly sees the `workToDo` again. I'm looking for a more in-depth explanation.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: That's understood. But it's not the issue here. This is not about fixing the program, it's about getting an explanation of the observed behavior.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how both threads can end up with null `workToDo` fields and spin forever @user2119598.

Comment: I stand corrected abut my comment above: It's rubbish, of course setting a breakpoint does not magically get things into order again once both Threads have their `workToDo` set to `null`. I think __torquestomp__ is absolutely right with his answer, it explains clearly what is happening.

Comment: I had that point before he did but whatever.  Glad it's working for you @user2119598.  You _will_ need to make sure of the synchronization points I mention in my answer as well.

Comment: @Gray: I marked the _best_ answer. **torquestomp**'s answer was just better understandable than yours in my opinion, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

my 2 cents....

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

class WorkerThread extends Thread {
    private AtomicReference<Runnable> work;

    public WorkerThread(String name) {
        super(name);
        work = new AtomicReference<Runnable>();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true){
            Runnable workToDo = work.getAndSet(null);
            if ( workToDo != null ) {
                workToDo.run();
            }
        }
    }

    public void setWork(Runnable newWork) {
        this.work.set(newWork);
    }
}
```

Comment: This solves the race condition, there is still potential for setWork to be called before the work item has been serviced. work should probably be a queue, or setWork should block until work is cleared before allowing it to be set.